# Which is right: "drop-down" or "drop down"?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, programming, compounds, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

What is the proper way to write this term when writing product documentation? Hyphenated or not?

> drop down list

or

> drop-down list?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If it's just the compound adjective, use *drop-down* list.

Note, however, that there are classes of components in various frameworks that are called **DropDown** or **DropDownList** or various alternatives of the same thing. In such cases use the framework name as is.

Comment: so we can use DropDown instead of Dropdown on the "react.js" components name?

Comment: @novonimo: I would spell it the same way the react.js documentation does, if it is a registered component. If it is not a case-sensitive class name, but is instead a generic term, I'd just lowercase the whole thing.

Answer (score 6):

In the dictionary it's drop-down: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drop-down

Also "drop-down" prevails on tech websites like apple.com or microsoft.com.

I think that this is the best indicator: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drop-down%2C+drop+down&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: The google-books link only compare the drop-down vs "drop down". Here's the full link, also comparing dropdown (combined): https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drop-down%2Cdrop+down%2C+dropdown&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdrop%20-%20down%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrop%20down%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdropdown%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3):

In the Merriam Webster dictionary, it is drop-down, but it also shows dropdown. — 
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drop-down "drop-down or dropdown noun, plural drop-downs or dropdowns "