# How to correctly name a list-like element in electronic forms?

Tags: word-choice, orthography

How to correctly name this in English (in an official documentation for IT system):

[image]

Should I name this:

- a listbox,
- a list box,
- a list-box,
- a combobox,
- a combo box,
- a combo-box,
- a dropdown,
- a dropdown list,
- a dropdown-list,
- a drop down list,
- a drop-down-list,
- *other name*.

[Similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/367651/22996) resulted with an [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/367655/22996) that form with space is much more popular and often used.

[Simiral Google Ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=listbox%2Clist+box%2Clist-box%2Ccombobox%2Ccombo+box%2Ccombo-box%2Cdropdown%2Cdropdown+list%2Cdropdown-list%2Cdrop+down+list%2Cdrop-down-list&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clistbox%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clist%20box%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clist%20-%20box%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccombobox%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccombo%20box%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccombo%20-%20box%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdropdown%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdropdown%20list%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrop%20down%20list%3B%2Cc0) reveals that:

- "listbox" is most popular,
- "dropdown", "dropdown list" and "combo box" are less popular, but usage is still significant,
- usage of all others falls below significance level.

It seems that "listbox" more popular than "dropdown" and "dropdown list", but this still doesn't answer my question, as I don't know, if "listbox" can be used correctly for pictured element?

Comment: Can you please provide more information about how you are planning to use the word in a sentence or context? Technical paper? Variable naming? Every-day vernacular among friends? We have no clue.

Comment: Questions about specialized terminology are better directed at domain experts than language experts. I might try asking at our sister site, [User Experience.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/), for a definitive answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because more suited for http://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Hank I thought that "in an official documentation for IT system" = "a technical paper" and no more information on context or planned usage is necessary. Your comment to the other answer looks like a perfect answer for this question. However, question itself is off-topic already, so no new answers allowed.

Comment: @trejder You are correct about the technical paper reference, I missed that.

Comment: @k1eran If you think it's off-topic, then why did you answer it? Lol

Comment: @Hank to be honest, I changed my mind - no law against that I believe.

Comment: @k1eran Nope. No law against it. Was just curious.

Comment: @Hank ... and I found the question interesting though it  seemed very domain-specific ... I  kind of wish I'd not noticed it now and had stayed out of it altogether .

Answer (score 3):

I always found this to be a sort of gray area, but I favor "drop-down list" in technical documentation. [Another thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9227/which-is-right-drop-down-or-drop-down) dealt with this nicely. The link specifies grammatically this could be considered a compound adjective, so the hyphen is acceptable. However, the general term "dropdown" appears more often in searches (according to [Google](https://www.google.com/trends/explore?q=dropdown,combobox)) when comapared with a slightly more obscure term like "combobox". This may change as trends change, but for now "dropdown" or "drop-down" seems more widely searched. But, if your document is meant for internal use then you should use whichever word your users or readers may know best.

Comment: I'd agree with this answer. W3schools refers to the element created by a "select" tag as a [drop-down list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

Comment: @Christy It really depends on where and how it's used. The OP wouldn't be able to accurately call it a *drop-down list* if it were in fact a *combo box*, although there aren't many differences. It would be better with additional information about usage from the OP.

Comment: @Hank I'd agree that combo box would suit for one where multiple selections can be made. I'm just going off the context from the image.

Comment: @Christy Comboboxes don't allow multiple selections; that's a listbox. Comboboxes are the same as a drop-down except you can also manually type text into the box like a textbox. From the image, there's no way to know for sure because a combobox can look like that when the options are open. Comboboxes are more prevalent in OOP programming as opposed to HTML. I'm not saying this answer is wrong, I just want the OP to clarify the intended usage.

Answer (score 1):

According  to Oracle the whole thing is a **combo box**, whereas the drop-down list is part of that *combo box*.

Quoting a [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) :

> [combo box] ... a text field with a small button abutting it. The user can type a value in the text field or click the button to display a **drop-down list**.

Comment: As per [Hank's comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/368094/how-to-correctly-name-a-list-like-element-in-electronic-forms/368331#comment859869_368096) a combo box is -- as you cite -- a combination of edit box and drop-down list.